# linking lex program, created with prefix

Tags: gcc, lex

My Lex file `main.l`:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
%}
%%
start               printf("Start command received\n");
stop                printf("Stop command received\n");
%%
```

Create `main.c` file command:

```
> flex -Palone -omain.c main.l
```

Then try to compile it:

```
> gcc main.c -o main -lfl
```

and got the following errors:

```
  "_alonewrap", referenced from:
      _alonelex in ccdqmJjR.o
      _input in ccdqmJjR.o
  "_yylex", referenced from:
      _main in libfl.a(libmain.o)
```

How to compile the lex program created with the prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use prefix, libfl is not for you. You must provide your own `main` function and your own `<prefix>wrap` function (or say you don't want one with `%option noyywrap`, see flex manual).

Comment: And obviously your main function can't be calling something called `yylex`, since you've changed the `yy` prefix!